# A smooth curve and mean value theorem

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

Assume that $f$ is smooth function defined in the unit disk $D: x^2+y^2\le 1$, and consider the integral $$I=\int_D f dxdy=\int_0^1r \int_0^{2\pi} f(re^{it})dt.$$

Then it is clear that for $r\in[0,1]$ there is $t_r\in [0,2\pi]$ so that $$I=2\pi \int_0^1 r f(re^{it_r})dr.$$ My question is, can we choose $t_r$ to depend smoothly on $r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can even choose $t_r$ to be independent of $r$. Indeed,
$$g(t):=\int_0^1 rf(re^{it})\,dr,\qquad t\in[0,2\pi],$$
is a continuous function satisfying
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}g(t)\,dt.$$
Therefore, there exists $t_0\in[0,2\pi]$ such that
$$I=2\pi\, g(t_0)=2\pi \int_0^1 r f(re^{it_0})\,dr.$$